# Spring: Implement two instances of a @Service with two instances of @Configuration linked to each respective service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

An existing utility exists that I am importing to my project. It is written similarly as these two classes

```
@Service
public class ServiceAccessorImpl implements ServiceAccessor {
  @Autowired private ServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration;

  public Response executeCall(){
     return callEndPoint(serviceConfiguration.getServiceEndPoint());
  }
}

@Configuration
@Data //automatically adds getters and setters
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="config")//pulls serviceEndPoint value from external config
//Assume external config has config.serviceEndPoint = "www.endpoint1.com"
public class ServiceConfiguration {
  private String serviceEndPoint;
}
```

In a separate project below I am importing the above into my project. I would like to have two instances of the same service with two unique and respective configuration classes. so that service1 is linked to config1 and service2 is linked to config2. My reasoning is I want one instance that only pulls the endpoint from the external configuration and another instance that I can use to set the endpoint. I have tried using things like @Qualifier but I cant figure out how to link the correct config with the correct service. I have a feeling that this may not be possible because ServiceConfiguration is privately scoped within ServiceAccessorImpl and I have no access through setters or constructors.

Controller Endpoint. The below is psuedo code of how I would like to implement my design. Autowiring in a *single* instance and using either endpoint works for that endpoint but not for both as shown below.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClass = ServiceAccessorImpl.class)
public class ServiceAccessorController {
 
  @Autowired private ServiceAccessor serviceAccessor1;
  @Autowired private ServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration1;

  @Autowired private ServiceAccessor serviceAccessor2;
  @Autowired private ServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration2;

   Response CallEndpoint1(){
       //www.endpoint1.com is already set here from external config
       return serviceAccessor1.executeCall();
   }
   
   Response CallEndpoint1(){
       serviceConfiguration2.setServiceEndPoint("www.endpoint2.com")
       return serviceAccessor2.executeCall();
   }

}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you need multiple instances of the same implementation, it's easier to not annotate it as a bean, and have a `@Configuration` provide the beans instead.

```
public class ServiceAccessorImpl implements ServiceAccessor {
  private ServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration;

  public ServiceAccessorImpl(ServiceConfiguration configuration) {
    this.serviceConfiguration = configuration;
  }

  public Response executeCall(){
     return callEndPoint(serviceConfiguration.getServiceEndPoint());
  }
}

// this one should just have @ConfigurationProperties, not @Configuration
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="config")
public class ServiceConfiguration {
  private String serviceEndPoint;
}
```

then in your service you can have a Configuration providing both instances:

```
@Configuration
public class BeansConfiguration {
    
  @Qualifier("service1")
  @Primary // optional, Spring will autowire this instance by default if no qualifier is given
  @Bean
  public service1(@Autowired ServiceConfiguration config) {
    // use the default config bean
    return new ServiceAccessorImpl(config);
  }

  @Qualifier("service2")
  @Bean
  public service2() {
    return new ServiceAccessorImpl(new ServiceConfiguration("www.endpoint2.com"));
  }
}
```

then you may consume both by using the qualifiers (note that you don't have to inject the configs here):

```
public class ServiceAccessorController {
 
  @Autowired
  private ServiceAccessor serviceAccessor1;

  @Autowired 
  @Qualifier("service2")
  private ServiceAccessor serviceAccessor2;

  Response CallEndpoint1(){
    return serviceAccessor1.executeCall();
  }
   
  Response CallEndpoint2(){
    return serviceAccessor2.executeCall();
  }
}
```

Comment: For my current implementation I was looking for the functionality you provided without changes to ServiceAccessorImpl and/or ServiceConfiguration if at all possible. It seems like it is not. Thank you for your detailed response. This is very informative and it seems  to be the best solution.